# Parse RSS files in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, rss

I am developing an Android app that downloads files from a server and played / displayed in the application itself.

Well, one of these files is in ***RSS 2.0 format*** and I'm a bit of a novice in this area.

I wonder what kind of content can be obtained from a file in this format (text, audio, video, image, etc.), that is, I'm going to have to be able to do once parsee its content (display text, play audio / video, display image, etc).

I would also like me indicate the **main steps to parse RSS files** in my own application. If you can add some links with clear steps I would appreciate it. I have read several posts related to RSS on this page (about *SAX, DOM or XML full parser*) but none are the steps to follow from start to parser RSS files...I'm a little lost.

Comment: You can probably get text, audio, video, image etc. Also, to parse RSS, get a parsing library and figure out how to use it. If you ask a question like this, you should include the code that you are trying to get to work, describe what it currently does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Good...that is my question, which library I can use for this purpose and how to use it? I have read something about SAX. You are responding me with my question ...